# My flutter app crashes and closes when i use listview.builder to display a large list of images

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, memory, memory-leaks

I want to create an application that displays 604 images of 165kb (96MB total image size) in a listview.builder, but as soon as I launch the application, the application crashes and closes, but when I reduce the number of images and I just display 200 the application works and I can scroll but over time it also crashes and closes, here is the code I use:

Public Repo : https://github.com/youcefdoukhi/mushaf_hafs

```
main() {
  runApp(
    const Test(),
  );
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 200,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String pageNum = "";

              if ((index + 1) < 10) {
                pageNum = "00${index + 1}";
              } else if ((index + 1) < 100 && (index + 1) > 9) {
                pageNum = "0${index + 1}";
              } else {
                pageNum = "${index + 1}";
              }
              return Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/mushaf_photos_2/page$pageNum.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use the ResizeImage class to reduce the size of the images but the problem persists, I also have the addAutomaticKeepAlives and shrinkwrap options but without result

[Image : Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw2h4.jpg)

Comment: what is the error code you got?

Comment: Theoretically fluuter Listview builder can handle really large Lists. Because its "deleting" the builded  images after and rebuilding them when you create them again.

Comment: I/Choreographer(28374): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/zygote64(28374): Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=24KB
I/zygote64(28374): After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=24KB
I/zygote64(28374): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: What device or emulator are you running this on? The error message feels like something an emulator that doesn't have enough memory would say.

Comment: Huawei Y9 (2019) 128GB 4GB RAM